# Lifetime annotation for closure caching example from Rust Book

Tags: generics, rust, closures

Trying to get into rust and had a pretty good time so far.

Been working through the official Rust Book: [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) and had a question come up about the [closures chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html).

The chapter creates a closure function with a cache mechanism. The task is to rewrite the implementation to use a HashMap instead of an Option to cache multiple results and use Generics to use more types than just u32.

My current working code looks like the following:

```rs
struct Cacher<'a, T, K: 'a>
where
    T: Fn(&'a K) -> &'a K,
{
    calculation: T,
    cache: HashMap<&'a K, &'a K>,
}

impl<'a, T, K> Cacher<'a, T, K>
where
    T: Fn(&'a K) -> &'a K,
    K: Hash + Eq,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<'a, T, K> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            cache: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    fn value(&mut self, arg: &'a K) -> &'a K {
        match self.cache.get(arg) {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v= (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.cache.insert(arg, v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

// inside the generate_workout function, the closure is to mock a long task
fn generate_workout(intensity: u32) {
    let mut expensive_result = Cacher::new(|num: &u32| {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        &num
    });

    println!("Result: {}", expensive_result.value(&intensity));
}
```

My question is about the needed lifetime annotation for the cacher struct and implementation. Is it needed, because my closure used for the specific cacher *expensive_result* in the generate_workout function is using the argument *num* as it's return value?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about the needed lifetime annotation for the cacher struct and implementation. Is it needed

The direct answer to your question is yes; whenever you use a reference inside a `struct` you must annotate it with a lifetime (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions)).

However, I suspect you already know that and isn't what you are really asking.  Therefore some guesswork, speculation and generic advise follows!

The current implementation is more restrictive than need be, and this is forcing you add a lot of lifetime annotation "noise".  You can actually simplify the `Cacher` `struct` a bit (by removing the `where` clause and removing the redundant `K: 'a` bound) but that isn't important here.

The first question to ask is, do I want `Cacher` to own its data or borrow it?  As currently written the definition of `Cacher` only allows for the latter.

A key insight that may help you is understanding that [T only contains owned types](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#1-t-only-contains-owned-types) is a misconception.

Once you understand that you can rewrite `Cacher` such that it may hold keys and values as *either* owned types or references (assuming that is flexibility that you want).

The other question you ask is whether you want to enforce the same requirements on both the keys and values of the cache.  As written both keys and values must be of the same (reference) type which is quite restrictive.  It also means that the *values* must also be `Eq + Hash` which likely isn't what you want.  Typically you want to specify separate generic parameters (i.e. K, V) for the key and value.

Finally, you may also want to look at using the [HashMap::entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API for your `value` implementation.